# Function to print multiple arguments together for logging

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write a generic log function that will accept string and object type of arguments of variable length and print them with some metadata related to the modules and sub modules. But I can't figure out a way print all the arguments together. Currently I am doing this.

```
// MODULE_NAME is different for every module of my project, so
// that I know which module the log belongs to.

function myLogger() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(MODULE_NAME, ":", arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

I am looking for a better way to do it which will work for following examples.

```
// MODULE_NAME = "TEST"
myLogger("error");
myLogger("error", err, ", result", res);
myLogger("hello", "world");
```

Output of the above calls should be

```
TEST : error
TEST : error {obj}, result {obj} 
TEST : hello world
```

Comment: You could use `join` to join them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log` actually accepts variadic arguments. You can do something like

```
function myLogger(...args) {
  console.log(MY_MODULE, ...args);
}
```

to pass all the arguments directly into console.log.

If your <s>life</s> company sucks and you can't use modern JS (with a transpiler), you can use [`.apply()`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/function/apply)

```
function myLogger() {
  console.log.apply(console, [MY_MODULE].concat(arguments));
}
```

Comment: This works for me I. I am using latest version for JS :D . Thanks mate !

Answer (score -1):

You can use winston logger.Through which you can generate five different level of logs. Please see my code below:

```
const winston = require('winston');
const fs = require('fs');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const logDir = 'log';
// Create the log directory if it does not exist
if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(logDir);
}
const tsFormat = () => (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();
const logger = new(winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        // colorize the output to the console
        new(winston.transports.Console)({
            timestamp: tsFormat,
            colorize: true,
            level: 'info'
        }),
        new(require('winston-daily-rotate-file'))({
            filename: `${logDir}/-results.log`,
            timestamp: tsFormat,
            datePattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            prepend: true,
            level: env === 'development' ? 'verbose' : 'info'
        })
    ]
});
 logger.debug('Debugging info');
 logger.verbose('Verbose info');
 logger.info('Hello world');
 logger.warn('Warning message');
 logger.error('Error info');
```